# How to correctly display a future inside of a Row?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, widget, future

I'm trying to display a list of bottom BottomAppBar icons but before that I have done some conditional checks for membership purposes.

Here is the entire code: https://dartpad.dev/82623d8d78149484eed5ae3be50dc297

A snippet of the problem I'm having (inside of the build widget):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: tabs[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              height: 70,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: // Should return _spacing here, but can't because it is a future and await doesn't work., 
children: // Should return buildChildren() here, but can't because it is a future and await doesn't work.),
            )));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to achieve this.
Do the following changes in your code:

Change the getMemberShip function:

```
Future<int> getMembership() async {
    // Your code
}
```

Change the buildChildren function:

```
List<IconButton> buildChildren(int level) {
var builder = [
   // Your code
];

if (level != 1) {
   // Your code
}
return builder;
```

}

Change the _spacing function:

```
_spacing(int level) {
   if (level != 1) {
     return MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly;
   } else {
     return MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween;
   }
}
```

Implement your build method like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: tabs[_currentIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
       shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
       color: Colors.red,
       child: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
         height: 70,
         color: Colors.white,
         child: FutureBuilder(
           builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.hasData) {
               int level = snapshot.data;
               return Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: _spacing(level),
                   children: buildChildren(level));
             } else if (snapshot.error) {
               return Text('Error occured');
             } else {
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
             }
           },
           future: getMembership(),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought of using the futurebuilder before but I didn't know how to lay it out.